# Select Option problems

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

selectpicker showing data outside dropdown before selection.It showing outside of the dropdown as well as in the dropdown.please tell me what is the problem and help me to fix this problem

```
<select class="selectpicker multi_menut_5" id="city_res" name="city" title="Select City" data-hide-disabled="true" data-live-search="true" onchange="/*get_sub_areas(this.value, '');*/
                  ">
 <optgroup label="Cities">
    <option value="">No Selection</option>
<?php
$cities = $db->get ("cities");
foreach ($cities as $city){ 
?>
    
    <option value="<?php echo $city['city_name']; ?>" <?php if($city['city_name'] == $selected_city) echo "selected"; ?> >
   
<?php 
        echo $city['city_name']; 
?>
    </option>

<?php 
} 
?>

<?php
$subareas = $db->get ("cities_sub_area");
foreach ($subareas as $subarea){ 
?>
    
    <option value="<?php echo $subarea['sub_area_name']; ?>,<?php echo $subarea['city'];?>" >
   
        <?php echo $subarea['sub_area_name']; ?>,<?php echo $subarea['city'];?>

    </option>

<?php 
} 
?>

<?php
$localities = $db->get ("localities");
foreach ($localities as $locality) {
?>
    
    <option value="<?php echo $locality['locality_name']; ?>"  >
        <?php echo $locality['locality_name']; ?>
    </option>

<?php 
}
?>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: Please check (and provide here) the *rendered* html.

Comment: What does it do if you disable the `selectpicker` class/initialisation?  ie just a plain `<select>`

Comment: then it works properly but in that case search filter disappears and i want search filter with dropdown because there is more than 500 options

Comment: Did you miss the first comment by freedomn-m? There might be something, in the rendered HTML, that is not visible in the PHP code. For instance: An option value might contain something that breaks the HTML. You're not using [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: Please also include the CDN for a the "selectpicker" js and css.   A quick google shows numerous select replacements called "selectpicker"

Comment: Can you please post the rendered html as suggested in previous comments.Also check the console tab if you see any error then post that as well.

Comment: dear i dont know how to render a html code please tell me how

Comment: Open your page in the browser where you have the error, right click on the browser: view source.  Or, F12 to open tools, inspect element click on element, locate / select the outer element in the Elements box, right click and copy outer HTML to get partial HTML

Comment: I did but the code is too long and can't be posted here

Comment: Then make it shorter.  Thats how you find bugs.  Make the arrays smaller by altering your query.  Read this  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something else, like using a function for the select options:

```
<select class="selectpicker multi_menut_5" id="city_res" name="city" title="Select City" data-hide-disabled="true" data-live-search="true">
<optgroup label="Cities">
<?php

function selectOption($value, $selected = '')
{
    if ($value == '') $value = 'No Selection';
    $value = htmlentities($value);
    echo '<option value="' . $value . '"' . 
         ($value == $selected ? ' selected' : '') . 
         '>' . $value . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
} 

selectOption('');

foreach ($db->get("cities") as $city) { 
    selectOption($city['city_name'], $selected_city);
}
    
foreach ($db->get("cities_sub_area") as $subarea) { 
    selectOption($subarea['sub_area_name']);
}
    
foreach ($db->get("localities") as $locality) {
    selectOption($locality['locality_name']);
}

?>    
</optgroup>
</select>
```